# FindFit, FindFormula, Fit, NonlinearModelFit - Which one to use? (I got no good curves & plots)

Tags: fitting, data, nonlinear, modeling

See this code, what mistake I did? (I got no plot)

```
data = {{595070, 340}, {595070, 340}, {595098, 339}, {595158, 
    340}, {595218, 340}, {595338, 348}, {595458, 351}, {595638, 
    355}, {595818, 356}, {596082, 360}, {596322, 361}, {596922, 
    366}, {597521, 367}, {598481, 367}, {599322, 375}, {600523, 
    380}, {601723, 382}, {603523, 384}, {605323, 388}, {608924, 
    394}, {612523, 396}, {619724, 403}, {626926, 408}, {648527, 
    417}, {670129, 419}, {691731, 423}, {712906, 428}, {734504, 
    429}, {756104, 428}, {776690, 430}, {798291, 430}, {819890, 
    433}, {841490, 435}, {863090, 436}, {884692, 437}, {906290, 
    438}, {927892, 441}, {949492, 442}, {971090, 441}, {992691, 
    441}, {1014291, 442}, {1035891, 446}, {1039491, 445}};
model = a + b*Exp[c*(e*x^f + g)^1.5];
fit = FindFit[data, model, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, x]
Show[Plot[Evaluate[model /. fit], {x, 595070, 1039491}], 
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

I got:

```
                           457884587
{a -> -2.186827693987254*10         , b -> 1., c -> 1., d -> 1., e -> 0.999993, f -> 1., 
 
  g -> 0.810866}
```

But I got no plot:

[image]

---

Similarly with

```
data = {{595070, 340}, {595070, 340}, {595098, 339}, {595158, 
    340}, {595218, 340}, {595338, 348}, {595458, 351}, {595638, 
    355}, {595818, 356}, {596082, 360}, {596322, 361}, {596922, 
    366}, {597521, 367}, {598481, 367}, {599322, 375}, {600523, 
    380}, {601723, 382}, {603523, 384}, {605323, 388}, {608924, 
    394}, {612523, 396}, {619724, 403}, {626926, 408}, {648527, 
    417}, {670129, 419}, {691731, 423}, {712906, 428}, {734504, 
    429}, {756104, 428}, {776690, 430}, {798291, 430}, {819890, 
    433}, {841490, 435}, {863090, 436}, {884692, 437}, {906290, 
    438}, {927892, 441}, {949492, 442}, {971090, 441}, {992691, 
    441}, {1014291, 442}, {1035891, 446}, {1039491, 445}};
model = a + b*Exp[c*(e*x^f + g)^1.5];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, x]
Show[Plot[Evaluate[model /. fit], {x, 595070, 1039491}], 
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

I read in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ many similar and related questions, but could not understand. (I am a new user of mathematica, currently using V12.1).

And still confused with FindFit, FindFormula, Fit, NonlinearModelFit differences.

Somehow I got able to put the starting values, but still not working.

I should get something similar to this (the red curve was drawn (by me) for illustration):

[image]

---

Please tell me what is wrong.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get that model? What would be reasonable values for the parameters? It seems very unlikely that you will ever get a reasonable fit without setting some initial values.

Comment: @MarcoB Sorry, I am sure that my model is fine to represent these data points. When I re-scaled the data (dividing x by 1000000 , and dividing y by 100), DESMOS found the parameters, this means my model is representative for my original data! https://i.imgur.com/klJatY4.png

Comment: Hussain, the fit you show is not very good at all. In particular it seems to completely miss the increasing trend towards the end. If this was my data, I would actually take the fit you showed as proof that your model does NOT actually fit the data. If you want further help with the model you have, please describe where it came from physically.

Comment: @MarcoB , dear, whether it is good or not good, the fitted curve should be as this https://i.imgur.com/klJatY4.png. If you have some data points, you should not change the model as per your convenient/happiness. Hope you understand my point. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see how your model could possibly fit the shape of the data.  I have to believe that you're being imaginative rather than having a model based on some theory.

The following simpler model can provide a reasonable description of your data:

```
data = {{595070, 340}, {595070, 340}, {595098, 339}, {595158, 
    340}, {595218, 340}, {595338, 348}, {595458, 351}, {595638, 
    355}, {595818, 356}, {596082, 360}, {596322, 361}, {596922, 
    366}, {597521, 367}, {598481, 367}, {599322, 375}, {600523, 
    380}, {601723, 382}, {603523, 384}, {605323, 388}, {608924, 
    394}, {612523, 396}, {619724, 403}, {626926, 408}, {648527, 
    417}, {670129, 419}, {691731, 423}, {712906, 428}, {734504, 
    429}, {756104, 428}, {776690, 430}, {798291, 430}, {819890, 
    433}, {841490, 435}, {863090, 436}, {884692, 437}, {906290, 
    438}, {927892, 441}, {949492, 442}, {971090, 441}, {992691, 
    441}, {1014291, 442}, {1035891, 446}, {1039491, 445}};

model = a + b Log[(x - c)/100000];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, {model, c < Min[data[[All, 1]]]}, {{a, 450}, b, {c, 595000}}, x];
fit["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 422.118, b -> 14.9335, c -> 594693.}
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[fit[x], {x, 594700, 1039491}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

But this suggests your issue isn't a *Mathematica* issue.

Using `NonlinearModelFit` gets one information to check on model fit, whereas `FindFit` does not.

```
fit["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Parameter table]

Comment: Sorry, I am sure that my model is fine to represent these data points. When I re-scaled the data (dividing x by 1000000 , and dividing y by 100), DESMOS found the parameters, this means my model is representative for my original data! https://i.imgur.com/klJatY4.png

Comment: Yes, I was wrong that your equation couldn't be bent into a shape similar to your data.  I'll update my answer later today.  But note that your equation has redundant parameters.  An equivalent model with one less parameter is `a1 + a2 Exp[a3 (x^a5 + a6)^1.5]`.  That suggests that while predictions from your model can approximate the data, interpretation of the parameters should not occur.

Comment: Yes please sir, your help would be really appreciated. I am a new user of mathematica V12.1 as I mentioned earlier. I have one idea, I am not sure if it will help us to solve my problem. The idea is: since my x values are large, then we may do as follows: data={{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}, then divide x values by 1000000 and divide y values by 100, so: data2={{x1/1000000,y1/100},{x2/1000000,y2/100},...}, then do FindFit for data2, once we get the model with the parameters, we can replace y by y/100 and replace x by x/1000000. Hope my idea is fine, and hope you understand my point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scaling the data is a good thing and I should have followed that advice I've given here many times.  But also please heed @MarcoB 's advice: either something is wrong with the data or something is wrong with the theoretical model (or even both).

Comment: I understand what @MarcoB means. But I say, if the model is wrong OR the data is wrong, OR both are wrong, then why Desmos could calculate the parameters for that model but mathematica did not. You understand my point sir?

Comment: Given that the model is overparameterized (at least one redundant parameter) and that Desmos didn't complain, it's a good thing that *Mathematica* didn't give you an answer. So I would be more concerned with Desmos.

Comment: Can you please try with `a1 + a2 Exp[a3 (x^a5 + a6)^1.5]` that you suggested earlier?

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html).

First observe from the shape of `data` (as defined in OP) that it follows some form of [`Log`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log.html) function.

```
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then start with a basic log function.  However, since the `x` values are large we can scale them down by the smallest value to assist the fit.

```
model = c Log[a x/Min[data[[All, 1]]] + b];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b, c}, x]
nlm["AdjustedRSquared"]
```

> ```
> FittedModel[15.032 Log[-9.23003*10^12+1.55212*10^7 x]]
> 0.999975
> ```

This gives a very good fit to the data.

Next plot `data` first in [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) as the option settings of the first plot are used by default and we want to see the all of the data points.  Also with `NonlinearModelFit` you should use the `"Function"` property for plotting.

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[Evaluate[nlm["Function"][x]], {x, 595070, 1039491}, PlotRange -> Full]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The fit looks as good as `"AdjustedRSquared"` implies.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that using this parameterization of the log model results in an estimate of a perfect correlation between `a` and `b`:  `nlm["CorrelationMatrix"]//MatrixForm`.  Using either `model = a + b Log[(x - c)/100000]` or `model = a1 + a2 Log[x + a3]` results in estimators that are much less correlated (and more numerically stable).

Comment: Sorry, I am sure that my model is fine to represent these data points. When I re-scaled the data (dividing x by 1000000 , and dividing y by 100), DESMOS found the parameters, this means my model is representative for my original data! https://i.imgur.com/klJatY4.png.

Comment: I should have added in my comment that it's not a critique of the kind of model fit.  The log model as you proposed first clearly fits the data better than the model proposed by the OP and at minimum suggests that either the data or the theoretical model or both have problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try starting simpler and work your way up. The "a" value you get above is very large. Your data is roughly constant. So start from there. Then add another term.

```
model = c;  

fit = FindFit[data, model, {c}, x;

    {c -> 398.163}

Show[Plot[Evaluate[model /. fit], {x, 595070, 1039491}], 
             ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Or

```
FindFormula[data];
```

Will give a piecewise answer with the Log function (I've suppressed output, but don't in your notebook).

```
Show[Plot[g[x], {x, 595070, 1039491}, PlotRange -> {0, 1000}], 
    ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]